# One word that can be used to represent student and professional

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I am having two options for users to select from, either they are a **Student** or they are a **Professional**. What one word can be used to represent both the names collectively? I tried a lot but couldn't  think of any.

The context is that i have a registration form for a test that has to be taken by a variety of people so i need to have a single word to represent student and professional.

Comment: What is the context? If it is for a transportation system, they could become university passengers or such

Comment: The context is that i have a registration form for a test that has to be taken by a variety of people.

Comment: Employment type?

Comment: yes sort of. Actually it would be specific and would be chosen by the person. eg. if a person is in IT he gives a test in IT or if a person is a graduate in English he gives a test in English.

Comment: Target, Audience, Applicant

Comment: yes, applicant type suits very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is *Applicant* based on your comments

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are asking:

> a *student* and a *professional* are both ___________ (noun).

This question has two types of answer.

You could be asking what superclass both belong to. In linguistics, this is called a *hypernym*. According to *WordNet*,[¹](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn)

> *student* (is a kind of) *enrollee* (is a kind of) *person*
>   *student* (is a kind of) *intellectual* (is a kind of) *person*

whereas

> *professional* (is a kind of) *adult* (is a kind of) *person*
>   *professional* (is a kind of) *athlete* (is a kind of) *contestant* (is a kind of) *person*
>   *professional* (is a kind of) *authority* (is a kind of) *expert* (is a kind of) *person*.

Thus if your question is about shared inherited hypernyms, the answer is that a *student* and a *professional* are both *people*.

Or you could be asking for a general category reflecting a significant property or attribute shared by students and professionals. But you don’t say what you consider significant. For example, if you consider literacy significant: they are both *literati* or *intelligentsia*. Or if you consider them to be types of vocation: they are both *occupations*, *callings*, or *job descriptions*.

Unfortunately you provided very little context in your question, so it is hard to know what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: Agreed that it's a little frail on the context. What kind of "professional" are we talking about? A professional student? Or a student who is a professional in another field?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer is *student or professional*.  But since you asked for a single word, and since you're describing this as a trait, I'll go with ***role***.

> **Role:**　 Student [_x_]　 Professional [___]